# Changing the connection string for a Typed Data Set

Tags: .net, connection-string, strongly-typed-dataset

I created a typed data set in one project, and moved it to another. The orginal connectionstring it created in the settings file was something like "myconnectionstring2". When I moved it to the new project I went into the project settings file and created a connection string called "myconnectionstring". I'm trying to get the typed dataset to use my new connection string but the generated code is still looking for "myconnectionstring2" . Where do I change the setting? I can't seem to find it in the typed dataset properties.

Comment: Not trying to criticize you or something, but if you said "visual studio" or "c#" anywhere in your question or tags then more people would understand that they don't care about your question instead of trying to help you and fail.

Comment: Good point. I added .net as a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. You have to click the "xxxTableAdapter" in the designer to get access to the connection string setting. You can specify a different connection string for each table adapter in your dataset. My problem was that I was looking for a DataSet/Top Level connection string property.

Comment: If you change the connection string at design time for one TableAdapter, all the other TableAdapters are changed instantly, so as far as I know you cannot assign different connection strings AT DESIGN TIME for every TableAdapter. Clearly, you are always allowed to change it at runtime if you have set the connection modifier of the TableAdapter to public.